# (Erro 404) -Controlador de rota não reconhecido no servidor

Tags: php, mvc, servidor, phpmyadmin, http-status-404

Olá, sou novo no mundo do desenvolvimento. Acabei de migrar um projeto do meu computador (local Windows) para o servidor na nuvem (VM Línux). Estou a usar uma arquitetura simples baseada em MVC. Soluções para o problema parecido que ví em pergurntas já feitas, não resolveu o meu problema. A questão é:

1 - Fiz todas as configurações necessárias no arquivo httpd.conf como:

```
DocumentRoot "/MyProject/public"
<Directory "/MyProject/public">
   AllowOverride all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

-#Eu descomentei as linhas abaixo.

```
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
Include etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
```

2- No arquivo httpd-vhosts.conf tenho:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin my@email.com
   DocumentRoot "/MyProject/public"
   ServerName "MyServerName.com"
   ErrorLog "logs/MyServerName.com-error_log"
   CustomLog "logs/MyServerName.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

3- No meu arquivo hosts eu adicionei:

```
127.0.1.1 MyServerName.com
```

Não estou usando nenhum arquivo .htaccess para aplicação e se devo usá-lo, não tenho idéia de como configurá-lo. O projeto funciona bem no meu servidor local (meu computador), estou a usar o Xampp nos dois cenários (Local e VM).

Além de outros, eu tenho um arquivo index.php no diretório público com o seguinte código:

```
require_once("../vendor/autoload.php");
$route = new \App\Route;
```

Alguma ideia de como resolver isso? Por favor!
Obrigado!

Comment: Manuel, tenho algumas perguntas pra tentar entender:
1 - Você está fazendo seu projeto em uma máquina virtual?

2 - Qual o diretório você está utilizando no Linux? É Ubuntu?

3 - Normalmente no Ubuntu o apache2 roda o server em /var/www/html, você chegou a olhar em qual pasta o xampp? Antigamente era /opt/lampp/htdocs .

Confirma esses pontos para você poder ajustar o caminho Document Root para por exemplo:
Document Root "/opt/lampp/htdocs/nomeprojeto"

Comment: o arquivo .htaccess você pode colocar na pasta public junto com index, usando por exemplo a config (código abaixo dentro do arquivo .htaccess):
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L]

Comment: Olá Gomes, O projeto começou a ser desenvolvido localmente, depois houve a necessidade de se passar numa máquina virtual na núvem. Localmente, estava a desenvolver no Windows. Na nuvem/Linux (Ubuntu) eu tenho projeto na raíz do sistema. O meu sistema tem o Xamp e o diretório padrão é /opt/lampp/htdocs.

Answer (score -3):

O problema é que eu estava a ignorar a configuração do .htaccess, pois no desenvolvimento local não foi preciso. Configurei-o como se apresenta abaixo e funcionou.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).